# If Wieferich primes are finite...Then what?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am wondering if $1093$ and $3511$ are the only Wieferich Primes, then what would it imply? (A Wieferich Prime is a prime satisfying the congruence $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod {p^2}$). I know of 3 cases:

1. There are infinitely many "non-Wieferich" primes...
2. Fermat Numbers are square-free
3. Mersenne Numbers having a prime exponent are square-free.

Does the finiteness have more consequences?
Thank you.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime) has a reasonably long list. The original motivation (Case I of the Fermat Last Theorem) is now of diminished relevance.

Comment: If the set of Wieferich primes, then we can find another proof of Fermat's last theorem for example.

Comment: Are you sure that 1. is true, because there is no proof for that (it's just a consequence of the abs conjecture or of another conjecture assuming that there are no three consecutive powerful numbers . But it's not proven yet.

Comment: Wikipedia says: "Rotkiewicz showed a related result: if there are infinitely many square-free Mersenne numbers, then there are infinitely many non-Wieferich primes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M_n=2^n-1$ be the $n$th Mersenne number, and $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ be the $n$th Fermat number.

$$M_{2^{n}}=2^{2^{n}}-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2^{2^{k}}+1)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}F_{k}.\tag{1}$$

$$F_{n}=\frac{M_{2^{n+1}}}{M_{2^{n}}}=\frac{2^{2^{n+1}}-1}{2^{2^{n}}-1}=2^{2^{n}}+1.\tag{2}$$

The Mersenne numbers form a divisibility sequence, i.e., if $M_m\mid M_n$ then $m\mid n$. This implies, since $2$ is prime, that Mersenne numbers $M_{2^k}$, with a subscript a power of $2$ only inherit factors from those preceding Mersenne numbers, $M_{2^{k-j}}$, $1\leqslant j\leqslant k-1$, having subscripts being a lesser power of $2$.  These inherited factors are seen by (1) to be the Fermat numbers.

Now (2) shows us the *primitive* prime factors of $M_{2^{n+1}}$ (by primitive we mean the primes that have never appeared before in the sequence ($M_n$)) are exactly those that make up the prime factorisation of $F_n$.

Hence if $1093$  and $3511$ are the only Wieferich primes, then Fermat numbers are square-free which immediately implies Mersenne numbers of the form $M_{2^n}$ are also square-free.

Answer (score 4):

A good survey about this question is the article [Wieferich Past and Future](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CE4QFjAFahUKEwjMyKqakb_GAhVIjCwKHXcADLY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.math.princeton.edu%2F~nmk%2Fwieferich42.pdf&ei=HJeWVczKLsiYsgH3gLCwCw&usg=AFQjCNH32CU1ZzoTCu-6_pRKUcjRCpbTgQ&bvm=bv.96952980,d.bGg) by Nicholas M. Katz. In section $1$ the consequences regarding FLT are discussed. However, since there is a proof of FLT the motivation for going further there has disappeared. However, other aspects related to elliptic curves, abelian varieties and semiabelian varieties are still of interest.