# Does there exist a prime number $p$ such that $p^2 \mid 2^{p-1}-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Does there exist a prime number $p$ such that $p^2 \mid 2^{p-1}-1$ ?

I tried for some small number $p$ and I think that it does, but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, though I bet that somebody has already asked it here before.

Comment: $3511$ also works.

Comment: See OEIS sequence [A001220](http://oeis.org/A001220).

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348180/if-wieferich-primes-are-finite-then-what).

Comment: the generalization to $p^k | a^{p-1}-1$ with $k \gt 1$  is the base for the so-called "Fermat-quotients" and is a field which is not yet fully answered. It is easy to find solutions with $a \gt p$ but difficult with $a \lt p$. Nobody knows whether there are even infinitely many wieferich primes... (fermat-quotients with $a=2,k=2$). I think Niels Abel was possibly the first one who made it a formal question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is.

> $1093$ does the job.

These primes are named Wieferich primes but we don't know if there are infinitely many.
For more see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime)